# Shortcut to show shortcuts markdown file (for windows)

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, productivity

I am looking for a way to very quickly open my personal Shortcut cheat sheet which is a simple markdown file. It contains a wide range of shortcuts for e.g. Chrome, Trello, Slack or VSC.

The closest thing to what I am looking for is the "cheatsheet" app but it is only available for mac https://www.mediaatelier.com/CheatSheet/

Is there something similar on Windows or is there some workaround to achieve something similar?

Answer (score 2):

I would use your browser for this. In Chrome, add the extension [Markdown Viewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-viewer/ckkdlimhmcjmikdlpkmbgfkaikojcbjk). Allow access to file URL's from the extensions settings menu, then open your `.md` file in Chrome. It will then render with all your hyperlinks and menu items, as per any other markdown reader.

Comment: That definitly is a valid option. Thanks for that. But I already have an average of 25 Chrome windows open at any given time so it would be great to find a solution that uses any other application then chrome